# How to get the GroupInfoCollection.Key in the DataGrid_OnLoadingRowGroup eventHandler

Tags: uwp, winui-3, windows-community-toolkit, winui

In the official MS documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/datagrid_guidance/group_sort_filter) and also in the sample application (https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/blob/b21dbe71f64e86ca9bb0ba6cfb4cb4d20e93765a/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.SampleApp/Data/DataGridDataSource.cs#L167) they use the `GroupInfoCollection` class.

Grouping works just as well with an `ObservableCollection`. However, my question here is how do I get the `GroupInfoCollection.Key` in the `DataGrid_OnLoadingRowGroup` eventHandler or what was the `Key` property intended for?

I would like to mark the UI according to which key is currently grouped by. However, I currently lack this information.

Answer (score 0):

> my question here is how do I get the GroupInfoCollection.Key in the DataGrid_OnLoadingRowGroup eventHandler or what was the Key property intended for?

You could refer to offcial code sample [line 124](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/blob/b21dbe71f64e86ca9bb0ba6cfb4cb4d20e93765a/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.SampleApp/SamplePages/DataGrid/DataGridPage.xaml.cs#L124). RowGroupHeader has CollectionViewGroup property, if you set Range as key of group, you could get the key like following.

```
ICollectionViewGroup group = e.RowGroupHeader.CollectionViewGroup;
DataGridDataItem item = group.GroupItems[0] as DataGridDataItem;
var key = item.Range;         
e.RowGroupHeader.PropertyValue = key;
```

Comment: I would like to be able to group by different properties and not just by range, for example. So I never know by which property I have grouped before. Your solution assumes that I knew beforehand which property I was grouping by. My problem would be solved with the following approach https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/issues/3089#issuecomment-604256939 because the current key is in `CollectionViewGroup.Group`.

Comment: Good, if you have found the solution, please feel free answer below and accept it.

Comment: I did it by set the DataContext dirrectly to the GroupHeaderViewModel:

e.RowGroupHeader.DataContext = <The view model you set for your GroupHeader, it could be accessed from ViewModel.xxxx.yyy